# Open shift internal registry lost connection with the cluster

Tags: networking, docker-registry, devops, openshift

As a result getting image pull error while submitting the deployment to the kube API. Even the docker registry pod IP is in connection but VIRTUAL IP of docker registry lost connection with the cluster.

**Observed these logs in server. Error response from daemon: Get http://VIRTUAL IP:5000/v1/users/: dial tcp VIRTUAL IP:5000: connect: no route to host**

Openshift internal registry lies in different project that is default. Previously, it was connected properly, the disconnection happened suddenly.

Epitome of the issue: Docker registry virtual IP lost connection with the entire openshift cluster. So, is there a possible way that we can re-establish the connection between the Open shift internal registry 'ss virtual IP and openshift cluster?

How can re-establish the connection the internal registry and the rest of the cluster??